# Raster pixel values changing when raster is clipped

Tags: raster, qgis-3, clip, sentinel-2

I have downloaded a couple of (Sentinel-2) raster files and would like to clip them down to be a smaller size.  However, when I clip them the output file has a wider range of pixel values than the original file.  For example, I clipped Band 2, which originally had values ranging from 0-1501.  However after I applied the clip function reducing the total number of pixels the values ranged from 0-2132.  I also tried mosaicking my (overlapping) files taking only the maximum value for each pixel to get rid of the 0 value areas and found the same thing to apply.  I have tried this in QGIS 3.16.11 and also in 3.24.0 and no difference between the results.

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening here?  I intend to use the pixel values to calculate NDVI so it is important that they are correct.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?  Is it separate to the clipping options?

Comment: That works perfectly!  You are correct, the exact numbers make a lot more sense.  That makes it the original range being 0-3902 and the clipped range being 0-3480.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're unlikely to have actually changed. These issues are usually caused by incorrect or poorly sampled approximate statistics. Recalculate the original and clipped statistics using exact instead of approximate method.

There's a few ways to do this

1. Use the [raster information tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.24/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#gdalgdalinfo) and tick the first two min/max
   and stats options.
2. There's also the [raster layer statistics tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgisrasterlayerstatistics), but the help doesn't state whether it uses exact or approx stats.
3. You can also specify to use exact stats in the [raster layer properties](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html#symbology-properties) -
   symbology - min/max values

Alternatively, use [gdalinfo](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html) from the commandline:

```
gdalinfo -mm -stats your_raster.tif
```

This is exactly what option 1 above does.